# How to ignore windows proxy settings with python urllib?

Tags: python, proxy, urllib

I want Python to ignore Windows proxy settings when using `urllib`. The only way I managed to do that was disabling all proxy settings on Internet Explorer. Is there any programmatic way?

`os.environ['no_proxy']` is not a good option, since I'd like to avoid proxy for all addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Pass to [urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) method

```
proxies={}
```

or try with:

```
urllib.getproxies = lambda x = None: {}
```

just after urllib import (Info found [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg10304.html)).

Comment: see comment for S.Mark's answer, please

Comment: the second solution really works. and `urllib.getproxies = lambda x = None: {}` should be added after `import urllib` as the document said.

Comment: Can confirm that proxies={} does not work under python3.5 but the other option does work for me.

Answer (score 3):

From the urlib2 [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.ProxyHandler): Class urllib2.ProxyHandler([proxies]) ... To disable autodetected proxy pass an empty dictionary.

So what we want to do is this:

```
import urllib2
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({}) # Pass empty dictionary to bypass proxy
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
socket = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
content = socket.read()
```

Comment: This did not work under python 3.5 for me. I tried using urllib.request in place of urllib2 because of the library change and the code did run but it was still trying to hit the proxy when urlopen is executed. systempuntoout's answer below worked for me in my case.

Answer (score 1):

According to [document](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#high-level-interface), you could pass, proxies=None or proxies={}

```
urllib.urlopen(some_url, proxies=None)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. `proxies=some_value` seems to extend the known proxies list instead of overriding it.

Comment: @Jaú, How about `os.environ['http_proxy']=None` ?

Comment: The documentation says it should be `proxies={}`

Comment: Incorrect. `proxies=None` tells urllib to take proxies from system

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble making request ignore the proxies.
These did not work.

```
proxies=None or proxies={}
```

This did work

```
proxies={'http':None}
```