# Python proxy support going through local connection with bad proxy

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, urllib2

I am using the following code to connect to a website using a proxy:

```
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"http://"+proxy})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

I am rotating a list of proxies and they change frequently. Whenever I come to a bad proxy in which this connection fails, the connection goes through my IP.

I tested this by spamming requests to whatismyip, and occasionally my IP would show up.

Can I stop a connection BEFORE it goes out if it is trying to use my home IP?

Comment: May help if you specify your OS

Comment: It may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645372/how-to-ignore-windows-proxy-settings-with-python-urllib

Comment: What is in your `proxy` variable? How do you populate it? Can you try test every proxy before using it via `ping` or some other method?

Comment: Proxy a single proxy passed in from a list of proxies. I could test but this could slow the script down. Also there is still a small chance ping could pass but connection could fail, and I dont want that.

Comment: What does "bad proxy in which this connection fails" means?
What response area you getting from proxy server? 
Could you make curl request, please:
curl -x"<proxy>" "<url>" -vv

Comment: There isn't an error. It just doesnt use that proxy in the connection and connects through my normal connection.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Could you provide a complete minimial code example that reads your public ip from `http://icanhazip.com` and uses `ProxyHandler` with a "bad proxy"? If I pass a bad proxy value to `ProxyHandler` then it just leads to `URLError`.

Answer (score 2):

I will try my best to explain this problem as I already had it before.

If there is a proxy set at the connection handler [urllib2](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/python/python-3/python/Lib/urllib2.py) will initiate, check it (correct address? user?password?port?) and use it for its connection.

If you look at the code the author even acknowledges that it is not optimal:

```
The opener will use several default handlers, including support
for HTTP and FTP.  If there is a ProxyHandler, **it must be at the
front of the list of handlers.**  (Yuck.)
```

So it calls the proxy before so if there is a proxy it will use if not No...

**BUT if there is any error** (bad url,bad proxy) it will **return NONE** to the connection handler.

So the connection handler will **connect as it does not have any proxy set.**

Now back to your problem:

You may check the proxies before using it and discard the bad ones. But still you have the problem that some proxies will die or change DURING your program is running.

For this you may modify urllib2 to return a localproxy instead of None.
In this scenario  **YOUR localproxy** will use a default page for everything so your program knows 'when' it has hit a problematic proxy.

This is a hack, maybe even ugly hack.

I did it and scraped the web happily afterwards.

Hope that helps you

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Can you point me in the right direction on pointing a no proxy connection to a different page? Cheers

Comment: Well there is a dirty trick...Just block the outgoing port 80 from the computer....
Proxies usually work at ports different than 80 (http) like (4290 squid, or 8080). If you block the outgoing connection to port 80 at your firewall... Your are done ;)
It is dirty but works and fast... I did that and finished the scrapping...